# Find non-matching subset of elements in the array - java

Tags: java, arrays

Given 2 arrays of String values such as:

```
String[] a1 = {"A", "B", "C"}  
String[] a2 = {"A", "B"};
```

where one array(`a1`) contains all the available String values and another array(`a2`) contains value I do not want to consider, how can I return an array with elements from a1 not contained in `a2`?

Constraints:
1> `a1` and `a2` will always contain unique valid values i.e. any value in `a2` will always be a value from `a1` and so there can never be a mismatch between `a1` and `a2`)
2> `a2` can be empty array

Here is what I have in mind:

```
List<String> nonMatch = new ArrayList<String>(a1.length - a2.length);
for (String a : a2)
{
    if (Arrays.binarySearch(a1, a) < 0)
    {
            nonMatch.add(a);
     }
}
return nonMatch.toArray();
```

But I wanted to know if there are any better solutions without degrading with performance

Comment: You could sort the arrays first then just iterate once, so you don't have to do a search at every string in a2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use a [`Set<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) - probably a `HashSet<T>`. For example:

```
Set<String> results = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(a1));
results.removeAll(Arrays.asList(a2));
return results; // Convert to an array if you really must
```

EDIT: My previous edit seems to have got lost, annoyingly.

I personally *wouldn't* convert back to an array unless you've got a compelling reason to do so. Life is generally more pleasant in Java if you stick to the Java Collection APIs (`List`, `Set`, `Map` etc) rather than arrays. You should also look at [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) which contains a bunch of nice functionality. In this particular case it wouldn't do *much* to improve things:

```
Set<String> results = Sets.newHashSet(a1);
results.removeAll(Arrays.asList(a2));
return results;
```

... but in general it's an incredibly useful library to have up your sleeve.

EDIT: To preserve order, use `LinkedHashSet<T>`:

```
Set<String> results = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(a1));
results.removeAll(Arrays.asList(a2));
return results; // Convert to an array if you really must
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Due to a change in requirement, I would have to maintain the order of the non-matching elements same as the order in array `a1` above. So if `a1={"A", "B", "C", "D"}` and `a2={"B","C"}`, the resultant array should **always** be in order `{"A", "D"}` for processing. If we are using a `Set`, I believe the order of processing would not be maintained.

Comment: @darkie15: It depends on what set you use - you could use a `LinkedHashSet` - that preserves order.

Comment: @Donkey: Please don't use comments to draw attention to unrelated questions.

Answer (score 4):

I think a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is probably the best way to go...

```
Set<String> diff = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(a1));
diff.removeAll(Arrays.asList(a2));
```

Comment: This wouldn't compile at the moment (you're trying to instantiate an interface in the second statement, and the first statement tries to use a non-existent constructor). Additionally, there's no need to create a set from `a2` to start with - `removeAll` can handle any collection.

Comment: @JonSkeet: was fixing as you where commenting

Comment: Fair enough. And while you were editing yours, it seems my previous edit to my answer was getting lost in the ether :(